# How could I find the growth rate of GDP

Tags: r

I have a data frame and would like to calculate the growth rate of nominal GDP in R. I know how to do it in Excel with the formula `((gdp of this year)-gdp of last year)/( gdp of last year))*100`. What kind of command could be used in R to  calculate it?

```r
year nominal gdp 
2003 7696034.9    
2004 8690254.3    
2005 9424601.9    
2006 10520792.8   
2007 11399472.2   
2008 12256863.6   
2009 12072541.6   
2010 13266857.9   
2011 14527336.9   
2012 15599270.7   
2013 16078959.8
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking as there is no GDP in your df

Comment: @PoGibas Actually, there is, is called `PIB` in his language, Spanish. (And in mine, Portuguese.)

Comment: Do **not** post data as images, edit your question and post the output of `dput(df)`.

Comment: Did you try something that didn't work? share some code. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Use this `GDP_delta = x/c(NA,x[1:(length(x)-1)]) -1` where x is your GDP vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use the `lag()` fuction from `dplyr`. It gives the previous values in a vector. Here is an example

```
data <- data.frame(year = c(2003:2013),
                   gdp = c(7696034.9, 8690254.3, 9424601.9, 10520792.8,
                           11399472.2, 12256863.6, 12072541.6, 13266857.9,
                           14527336.9, 15599270.7, 16078959.8))
library(dplyr)
growth_rate <- function(x)(x/lag(x)-1)*100 
data$growth_rate <- growth_rate(data$gdp)
```

Comment: Note that this works only with the `dplyr` library. Not sure what the base-`R` `lag()` function is for, but it doesn't help compute the growth rate...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best for you to get familiar with data tables, and do something like this:

```
library(data.table)

dt_gdp <- data.table(df)

dt_gdp[, growth_rate_of_gdp := 100 * (Producto.interno.bruto..PIB. - shift(Producto.interno.bruto..PIB.)) / shift(Producto.interno.bruto..PIB.)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A base-R solution:

```r
with(data, 
    c(NA,                  ## augment results (growth rate unknown in year 1)
       diff(gdp)/          ## this is gdp(t) - gdp(t-1)
          head(gdp, -1))   ## gdp(t-1)
              *100)        ## scale to percentage growth
```

`head(gdp, -1)` is perhaps a little too clever. `gdp[-length(gdp)]` (i.e. "`gdp`, excluding the last value") would be slightly more idiomatic.

Or

```r
(gdp/c(NA,gdp[-length(gdp)])-1)*100
```