# Calculating regional economic growth serires, ie. the growth series of the four countries put together

Tags: r

I want to calculate the regional growth rates for selected countries using real gdp series for 10 years in R.Any idea how i could solve this, please?

```r
country1<-c(7297.92,7606.31,7831.29,8288.33,8455.79,9312.52,9715.96,10273.14,10680.06,11250.53,11909.55,12544.70,13127.16)

country2<-c(6867.71,7490.89,7507.96,7768.33,7870.16,8320.16,9236.60,9820.07,10537.69,11195.42,11406.84,12161.22,12690.59)

country3<-c(36451.25,36471.89,36244.85,36100.36,36874.38,39475.09,42137.73,44531.85,46815.82,47725.57,46738.43,46795.16,46014.77)

country4<-c(36039.85,37943.41,39415.40,41327.04,42678.11,44395.22,46435.70,48385.18,50656.26,52899.57,55124.29,57626.41,60388.82)
```

I went through the REAT package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/REAT/REAT.pdf) but could not figure out how to get it done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I find the growth rate of GDP in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727524/how-could-i-find-the-growth-rate-of-gdp-in-r)

Comment: the dplyr package has a lag function. (country1/lag(country1)-1)*100